# DOCUSIGN iframe returning url with parameters

Tags: docusignapi

How to pass parameters(envelope,PF and r ID) within iframe while returning URL in embedded docusigning??? If I enter the POWERFORM link on browser I'm returning URL with the parameters(envelope,PF and r ID) but if I run the below mentioned HTML code within IFRAME i'm unable to get the parameters.......WHY????

```
<title>IFrame PowerForm Sample</title>
<style type="text/css">
  body { background-color: #fefdfc;}
  p.description { width: 500px; border: 1px solid #cfc; padding: 20px; }
  .form_cont { border: 1px solid #cfc; padding: 20px; width: 1024px; background-color: #cd9;}
  .top_cont { width: 1124px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
  #dswpf { width: 1024px; height: 700px;}
</style>
```

This page embeds a DocuSign Web PowerForm into an HTML iframe.
       This allows a website's branding and design to be retained while a user fills out 
       and signs a form.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any possibilities that I get the parameters after breaking out of iFrame in URL. That would also be fine if I get parameters in new webpage after customer finish signing the document within Iframe.